# How to know if my radio button is checked? AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

guys I did a code for knowing if my checkbox is checked and works fine:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="UserController">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="Table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">

                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked"/></td>
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>

     </div>   
</div>
```

This is the Angularjs code:

```
function UserController($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        { checked: false, name: 'Jorge', lastName: 'Martinez', phone: 012345 },
        { checked: false, name: 'Juan', lastName: 'Perez', phone: 78964 }
    ];

    $scope.updateUser = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function (user) {
            if (user.checked) {
                user.name = $scope.nameUpdate;
                user.lastName = $scope.lastNameUpdate;
                user.phone = $scope.phoneUpdate;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

The problem is when I change the checkbox for a radio button:

```
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="user.checked"/></td>
```

When I do this, this value "if(user.checked)"  appears as "undefined".
Some one that knows how to fix this or how to know if the radio button is checked or not in the AngularJS controller.

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

you'll want to have multiple radio buttons, each with it's own value to set some property to (although this is weird for a yes no you are better off with a checkbox, but if you had multiple values this is how radio buttons work)

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="user.checked" ng-value="true" />Yes
<input type="radio" ng-model="user.checked" ng-value="false" />No
```

when you have just one radio button, if it is not checked by default or you have no ng-value it will be undefined, but also having only one radio button, you could never unselect it.

Comment: The problem appears in the angular controller, when I check a radio button in the UI and I loop the array of the users the propertie user.checked is false always.                                      if (user.checked) {
                user.name = $scope.nameUpdate;
                user.lastName = $scope.lastNameUpdate;
                user.phone = $scope.phoneUpdate;
            }

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the radio button a value.

```
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="user.checked" value="true"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" ng-model="user.checked" value="false"/></td>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/p4pf935y/)

Comment: When I do that, the property user.checked appears as false always, in the controller. if(user.checked) {
                user.name = $scope.nameUpdate;
                user.lastName = $scope.lastNameUpdate;
                user.phone = $scope.phoneUpdate;
            }

Comment: Thanks Malkus, but I think you don't understand me, just i want to know if the radio button is checked or not and I want to know that in the controller when I do click in another button. The fiddle that you did it doesn't anything when I do click in the button.

Comment: It does, it is logging to the console.  Open your browser console, usually `F12` When your browser is open.  And if you don't have a radio selected it will not log that user.  Otherwise it puts the value.